# How to store data in session

Tags: java, android, sqlite, session

I have a doubt to storing data in database without login like e-commerce app.
In back-end   the data is store by userID to store data but client side is the app used without login and the product can be add to cart and add to wish list  so how can that possible to store data in android.Any help or idea it will more helpful.Thanks

Comment: Hi @MustafaShaikh, you can use SharedPreferences or SQLite database using Room to store data as Noobie1234 suggested in below answer. For more info, you can study in order to use them- 1. SharedPreferences- https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences
2. Room Persistence Library- https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room
3. Sample using Room (Assuming you are familiar with SQLite)-  https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the below code

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); //0 - for private mode
Editor editor = pref.edit();
```

For storing the data

```
editor.putString("key_name", "string_value"); // Storing string
editor.commit(); // commit changes
```

For Retrieve

```
pref.getString("key_name", null); // getting String
```

To Clear

```
editor.remove("Key_name"); // will delete key name
editor.commit(); // commit changes
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either store the temporary data in SharedPrefs or in the SQLite database using Room.
When the user adds/removes the product simply update the database or prefs and when user wants to buy move to the login screen > after successful login read the data from the database and proceed as you want.
When the user clears the cart or wishlist, clear the respective tables.